# How to add a segmentation camara to robot

Tags: gazebo, urdf, gazebo-11, gazebo-ignition

As the title mentioned, I want to add a segmentation camera to my robot for a gazebo simulation. I've built my robot using urdf and have already added a realsense d435 cam on it. I do find [documents](https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/6.0/segmentationcamera_igngazebo.html) for segmatation camera but there're two problem to it.

1. It seems that the segmentation cam I found was made for sdf file and didn't mention about how to install it in urdf.
2. It only works in ignition gazebo. Though I do installed both gazebo and ignition gazebo, I'm currently using gazebo classic and doesn't know how to change my project setup to it.

If there's a way to use realsense's input that was already installed on the robot as the source of the segmentation simulation will be fine too. This is my project in [github](https://github.com/brian2lee/forklift_test/tree/master/src/ros1_wiki/forklift). Down below is the urdf code of the robot and my installed gazebo version.

> Gazebo version 11.14.0. 
>  Gazebo Fortress 
>  ROS 1

forklift.xacro.urdf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="forklift">
   
    <link name="base_footprint"/>

    <link name="base_link">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <mass value="50.0"/>
            <!--
            <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" iyy="1.3419385416666667" iyz="1.3419385416666667" izz="2.296875"/>
            -->
            <inertia ixx="1.3419385416666667"
                iyy="1.3419385416666667"
                izz="2.296875"
                ixy="0.0"
                ixz="0.0"
                iyz="0.0"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual name="">
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.525 0.525 0.2155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0"/>
                <texture filename=""/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.525 0.525 0.2155"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>
    <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <parent link="base_footprint"/>
        <child link="base_link"/>
    </joint>

<!--    ***   wheels   ***   -->    

    <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="name x y">
        <link name="wheel_link_${name}">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="1.0"/>
                <!--
                <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" 
                    iyy="0.0009333333333333333" iyz="0.0009333333333333333" izz="0.0018"/>
                -->        
                <inertia ixx="0.0009333333333333333"  
                    iyy="0.0009333333333333333"  
                    izz="0.0018"
                    ixy="0.0"
                    ixz="0.0"
                    iyz="0.0"/>
                </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="0.06" length="0.02"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="black">
                    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="0.06" length="0.02"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <gazebo reference="wheel_link_${name}">
            <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
        </gazebo>

        <joint name="wheel_joint_${name}" type="continuous">
            <origin xyz="${x} ${y} -0.100250" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="wheel_link_${name}"/>
            <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>

            <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="0.1" />

        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>

<!--   ***   fork base   ***   -->
    <xacro:macro name="fork_base" params="name y">
        <link name="forkbase_link_${name}">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="0.5"/>
                <!--
                <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" 
                    iyy="0.0005208333333333334" iyz="0.0004208333333333334" izz="0.00010833333333333334"/>
                    -->
                <inertia ixx="0.0005208333333333334"  
                    iyy="0.0004208333333333334"  
                    izz="0.00010833333333333334"
                    ixy="0.0"
                    ixz="0.0"
                    iyz="0.0"/>
            </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.01 0.05 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="green">
                    <color rgba="0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.01 0.05 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <gazebo reference="forkbase_link_${name}">
            <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
        </gazebo>

        <joint name="forkbase_link_${name}" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.2675 ${y} -0.10025" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="forkbase_link_${name}"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>

<!--   ***   fork   ***   -->
    <xacro:macro name="fork_link" params="name">
        <link name="fork_link_${name}">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="0.5"/>
                <!--
                <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" 
                    iyy="0.00010833333333333334" iyz="0.0026083333333333336" izz="0.0027083333333333334"/>
                -->
                <inertia ixx="0.00010833333333333334"  
                    iyy="0.0026083333333333336"  
                    izz="0.0027083333333333334"
                    ixy="0.0"
                    ixz="0.0"
                    iyz="0.0"/>
            </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.25 0.05 0.01"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="green">
                    <color rgba="0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.25 0.05 0.01"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <gazebo reference="fork_link_${name}">
            <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
        </gazebo>

        <joint name="fork_link_${name}" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.13 0 -0.045" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="forkbase_link_${name}"/>
            <child link="fork_link_${name}"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>

    <xacro:include filename="$(find realsense2_description)/urdf/_d435.urdf.xacro" />
    <xacro:sensor_d435 name="camera" topics_ns="camera" parent="base_link" publish_pointcloud="true">
        <origin xyz="0.2625 0 -0.10775" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </xacro:sensor_d435>  

<!--   ***   combine component   ***   -->
    <xacro:wheel name="back_right" x="-0.150000" y ="-0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="back_left" x="-0.150000" y ="0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="front_right" x="0.150000" y ="-0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="front_left" x="0.150000" y ="0.272513"/>

    <xacro:fork_base name="right" y ="-0.055"/>
    <xacro:fork_base name="left" y ="0.055"/>

    <xacro:fork_link name="right"/>
    <xacro:fork_link name="left"/>

</robot>
```